# Creating and opening database with FMDB(Objective-c Database Library)

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb

I'm developing iOS App with FMDB(Database Library of using SQLite easily).

For creating and opening a database, I'm writing down the following code.

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = [manager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                 inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];

NSURL *documentDirs = [paths lastObject];
NSURL *writableDBPath = [documentDirs URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.db"];

NSString *writableDBPathString = [writableDBPath path];
NSLog(@"DB path:%@",writableDBPathString);

FMDatabase *myDatabase = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPathString];

[myDatabase open];
```

After running my Xcode Simulator, the above "NSLog" shows the following message, so I guess I can get the collect path.

```
2014-07-14 02:42:18.296 ninethtest[2064:a0b] DB path:/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/D71C7BC8-8F01-486F-81FA-E1Exxxxxxx/Documents/test.db
```

However, the following error message appears at "NSURL *writableDBPath = [documentDirs URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.db"];" and "[myDatabase open];" in the above code.

```
Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0xbf7ffffc)
```

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe try a `.sqlite3` extension?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes,I've already tried libsqlite3.dylib. Do you have any idea regarding to this problem?

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means that the pointer you are looking for has been deallocated. Look at the answer I just wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing this to get your database path.

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testDB.sqlite3"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your method, but I got the same error.Could you tell me another method?

Comment: If that is not working, then I do not think that part of the code is the problem. Are you using CocoaPods? If so, I would make sure you are using the latest version.